# Selective Increment in loop (if it makes sense)

Tags: c++

Ok so it may sound a bit confusing but I'll try to keep it simple. I have to run a loop for a specific task.

Check this code for instance;

```
if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= store; i++) /* store variable is assigned digit 3 */
        {
            char ch2 = 'A';
            for (int j = store; j >= i; j--)
            {
                cout << ch2;
                ch2++;
            }
            for (int space = 1; space < i; space++)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            ch = ch - 1;
            for (int j = store; j > i; j--)/*will run two times*/
            {
                cout << ch;
                ch--;
            }
            ch = save; /*save has been assigned the original character value*/
            cout << endl;
        }

    }
```

Here the second inner J loop will run two times but I need to run it three times. I know I can put j>=i but that wont work for me as I'm dealing with characters and it will put a special char there. any other way it can be done?

Comment: Instead of `ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'` I suggest you use [`std::isupper(ch)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper). Comparing a range like you do is non-portable. As is all your characters handling (like e.g. `ch2++`).

Comment: *I know I can put j>=i but that wont work for me as I'm dealing with characters and it will put a special char there* <-- Please clarify. `j > i + 1`?

Comment: @super j is assigned the value of store which is 3 (here). if that helps

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry I'm new to c++ and haven't gotten to concepts like std

Comment: @scypx It does not. I don't understand what the problem is at all. All you say in the question is that you have a loop that you runs twice and you want it to run three times. So just let it run one more time?

Comment: @super If I let it run, it gives me a special char "&" which I don't need

Comment: When you state "store variable is assigned digit 3" do you mean the *integer value* `3`, or the *character*  `'3'`? Because they are two very different things. (With the common ASCII encoding, the character `'3'` has the integer value `51`.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude integer value

Comment: Can you give sample Input and Output? That'd help us in helping you.

Comment: Use a debugger. It should be relatively easy to follow the code line by line and make any desired adjustment when the program does not do what you want at that given point.